# postgrsql xml schema xsd failed to compile

Tags: xml, postgresql, xsd

database: pruebadb

```
CREATE DOMAIN public.cod_pk AS bigint;
CREATE DOMAIN public.text_entidad AS character varying(100);

create table prueba (
    cod_prueba cod_pk not null,
    prueba text_entidad not null,
    primary key(cod_prueba),
    unique(prueba)
);
insert into prueba (cod_prueba, prueba) values (1,'prueba1');
insert into prueba (cod_prueba, prueba) values (2,'prueba2');

select table_to_xmlschema('prueba', true, false, '')
```

### prueba.xsd

```
<xsd:schema
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsd:simpleType name="Domain.pruebadb.public.cod_pk">
  <xsd:restriction base="BIGINT"/>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="Domain.pruebadb.public.text_entidad">
  <xsd:restriction base="VARCHAR_100"/>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="BIGINT">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:long">
    <xsd:maxInclusive value="9223372036854775807"/>
    <xsd:minInclusive value="-9223372036854775808"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="VARCHAR">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:complexType name="RowType.pruebadb.public.prueba">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="cod_prueba" type="Domain.pruebadb.public.cod_pk" nillable="true"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="prueba" type="Domain.pruebadb.public.text_entidad" nillable="true"></xsd:element>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="TableType.pruebadb.public.prueba">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="row" type="RowType.pruebadb.public.prueba" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="prueba" type="TableType.pruebadb.public.prueba"/>

</xsd:schema>
```

SELECT table_to_xml('prueba', true, false, '')

### prueba.xml

```
<prueba xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<row>
  <cod_prueba>1</cod_prueba>
  <prueba>prueba1</prueba>
</row>

<row>
  <cod_prueba>2</cod_prueba>
  <prueba>prueba2</prueba>
</row>

<row>
  <cod_prueba>3</cod_prueba>
  <prueba>prueba3</prueba>
</row>

</prueba>
```

**`xmllint --schema prueba.xsd prueba.xml --noout`**

prueba.xsd:8: element simpleType: **Schemas parser error** : simple type 'Domain.pruebadb.public.text_entidad', attribute 'base': The QName value 'VARCHAR_100' does not resolve to a(n) simple type definition.
**WXS schema prueba.xsd failed to compile**

I just want to check the xml file, what is the problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Didn't define `VARCHAR_100`. Exactly what the error-message says.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a correct XSD.

There is no need to define new data type:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="VARCHAR">
```

The built-in `xsd:string` has its own facets to define string's maximum length.
Please see below.

Overall, the XSD could be refined even further.

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:simpleType name="Domain.pruebadb.public.cod_pk">
        <xsd:restriction base="BIGINT"/>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="Domain.pruebadb.public.text_entidad">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="100"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="BIGINT">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:long">
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="9223372036854775807"/>
            <xsd:minInclusive value="-9223372036854775808"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="VARCHAR">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:complexType name="RowType.pruebadb.public.prueba">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="cod_prueba" type="Domain.pruebadb.public.cod_pk"
                         nillable="true"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="prueba"
                         type="Domain.pruebadb.public.text_entidad"
                         nillable="true"></xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="TableType.pruebadb.public.prueba">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="row" type="RowType.pruebadb.public.prueba"
                         minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="prueba" type="TableType.pruebadb.public.prueba"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

**XSD #2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="prueba">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="row"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="row">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="cod_prueba" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="prueba" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: xmllint --schema prueba.xsd prueba.xml --noout
prueba.xsd:8: element simpleType: Schemas parser error : simple type ????

Comment: @Arcadio, Before I posted the answer, I checked it with Saxon 9.8.0.12. It is absolutely legit XSD.

Comment: @Arcadio, I run it in the Stylus Studio. So no command line is involved. Please connect with me on LinkedIn.

Comment: Yours is not a solution for me, I am asking for xmllint or something that I can run from the command line, I can automate.

Comment: @Arcadio, it doesn't work this way. A legit XSD is a legit XSD based on the w3c standards, and it should  work everywhere. As I mentioned earlier, your XSD could be simplified. Check it out, the XSD #2.

Comment: My xsd file is the one obtained from postgresql with its tools and it is the basis of my question. I seek to automate the verification of the results obtained from postgresql with executable tools on the command line; I understand your comments and answer but I think it does not suit my question. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Arcadio, did you have a chance to try the second XSD?

Comment: I have used for example freeformatter with the same result ... I do not have access to saxon

Comment: @Arcadio, as I already explained, it has nothing to do with Saxon. It is a generic XSD that should work everywhere.

Comment: In https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html it doesn't work either, for example

Comment: @Arcadio, I just tried your input XML and the XSD #2 on that web site. And everything is working. The XML is valid against the XSD #2.

Comment: But I don't want to modify anything, I want to execute the postgresql statements and then proceed, I suppose that what will have to be refined are the postgresql statements select table_to_xmlschema ('test', true, false, '') and SELECT table_to_xml ('test ', true, false,' ') no?